# Once I've started moving in Card Hunter, can I cancel my choice?

Tags: card-hunter

In the process of looking at my hand in [Card Hunter](http://www.cardhunter.com/), I clicked on my character's movement ability.

However, I don't want to move yet -- is there a way to cancel my selection and pick a different card instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, moves cannot be cancelled:

> Any card containing a move (i.e. blue and half-blue cards) **cannot be cancelled once clicked**.

Source: [Cancelling Moves - Thoughts and Suggestions](https://forums.cardhunter.com/threads/cancelling-moves-thoughts-and-suggestions.1595/). Assussanni @ Card Hunter Forum. May 9, 2013.

> Because: **playing a move card can trigger other cards, revealing them to you or your opponent** and so we can't allow you to cancel that play.

Source: [Cancelling Moves - Thoughts and Suggestions](https://forums.cardhunter.com/threads/cancelling-moves-thoughts-and-suggestions.1595/#post-18930). Jon *apud* skip_intro @ Card Hunter Forum. May 9, 2013.